# Prove that the interior and closure of a convex set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are convex.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-optimization

I have read individual proofs of the interior and closure of a convex set but hoping to use one to prove the other. I want to use points on the boundary of $K$ to say that every line segment with endpoints $a,b\in int(K)$ is already contained on a line segment with end points $c,d\in bd(K)$.

Am I trying to simplify too much or can this be done? Also trying to use the proper notation since I struggle to turn sentences into the correct mathematical notation.

Comment: My opinions: (1) You're trying to simplify too much. (2) Make sure "correct mathematical notation" uses words along with the necessary symbols. It's often easier to read "implies" than "$\implies$;

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? This is a very unnatural and barren way to attack an otherwise simple problem.